# Using two MIDI inputs with Arduino UNO (with one serial)

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, midi

Would it be possible to use TWO MIDI inputs (and a MIDI output) on an Arduino having only one RX/TX serial port? Timing will be somewhat critical so a software serial port is not usable probably. I need to listen continuously to both MIDI (in) ports not to miss messages.

Or is it better to use an Arduino Mega having 4 serial ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Mega. SoftwareSerial is shaky at best and cripples everything else while it runs, and there really is no substitute for real hardware UARTs.

Alternatively look around and see if you can find a board based around the ATMega328-PB (note the "B") which has a second UART built in.

Comment: I can find the IC, but It's in SOP format, and since I have barely 0 soldering experience, the safest way is to go for a Mega for now. But nice to know there is an alternative.

Comment: FYI: I went for a Mega and now use 3 UARTS without any problem (leaving the 4th for debugging).